# Programmatically maintaining sitemaps

Tags: sitemap, lamp, traversal, maintainability

Hoping someone can chime in on an ideal methodology.

I don't want to [run my site through a crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396749/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-sitemap) every month to add new pages to my sitemap, I'd like some robust systematic method to do so, because maintaining it by hand seems very prone to *ahem* human forgetfulness.  Is there some sorta way to programmatically validate new controllers, controller methods, views, etc. to some special controller?  What I'm picturing is some mechanism that enforces updating the sitemap whenever you create a new controller method or view.  I work in LAMP stack if that's relevant.  [This guy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426629/php-script-to-automatically-create-sitemaps) is doing it through the file system and that's not what I want for a public facing sitemap.

Perhaps there's another best practice for this type of maintenance other than the concept I'm proposing.  Would love to hear how everyone else does this! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your site is content based, best practise is reading database periodically and generating each contents link. With this method you can specify some subjects are more prior or vice versa in sitemap.
That method already mentioned before at topic that you linked.

Else, you can hold a visited pages list (static) at server-side. Or just log them. After recording your site traffic, without blocking the user experience, I mean asynchronously, check the sitemaps and add your page links there. You can specify priority with this method too, by visiting intensity of your pages and some statistical logic.

Comment: Interesting suggestion about analyzing logs.  However that is reactionary - I'm thinking of a system that works in real-time, perhaps it prevents me from committing new code without first updating the sitemap or something to that effect.