# How to create a sitemap.xml for my localhost website?

Tags: javascript, xml, localhost, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have no idea about XML so please anyone can guide me about it.I want to create a sitemap.xml for my code.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate a sitemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396749/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-sitemap)

Comment: Basically you are asking us to teach you how to make a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+create+a+sitemap.xml+for+my+localhost+website)...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why did you tag your question with [tag:javascript]?